# Hide text going beyond DIV element

Tags: html

I have a DIV element with fixed width having some text which doesn't have any spaces for HTML parser to automatically break into multiple lines. The text is going beyond the limit of the DIV and messing out the pgae:

1. Is there anyway to make text going beyond the boundary invisible?
2. Is it possible to break it into multiple lines, or -even better- break into multiple lines with a hypen at the end of each broken line?

Regards,
Rafid

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this with [*CSS*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS).

> Is there anyway to make text going beyond the boundary invisible?

Yep: [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/overflow)

```
#yourDivId {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

> Is it possible to break it into multiple lines

Yep: [`word-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Word-wrap)

```
#yourDivId {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that word-wrap is supported in all browsers.

Comment: @Andrew Cooper: see https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Word-wrap#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 2):

You could use CSS:

```
div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or:

```
overflow: auto;
```

For more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is to use the following style:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Alternatively, if you want to be able to scroll in the div to see the content you can do

```
overflow: auto;
```

or

```
overflow: scroll;
```

To do what you ask in your second question you'd need some javascript.

Comment: Yes, I am ok with JavaScript, but how will I know at which letter the text starts to go beyond the boundary? You know, I am not using Courier Font to have fixed font width (though I wouldn't like to hard code these values anyway). Any idea?

Comment: No.  I'd have to play around with it myself.  It wouldn't surprise me though if this is already available in a JQuery plugin.